# Why i don't get iligal state expression from startService on Android O

Tags: android, service, foreground-service

According to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pumf_4yjTMc&t=57s
in 0:56 it means that you cannot start a service when your app is in the background.

It will cause `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed` to start service `Intent`. But when I try `startService OnStop` or with broadcast `onRecive()` when the app is in background it's not crashing and I expect it to crash. I'm using Pixel 2 API 27 emulator.

MainActivity.class

```
switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.button:
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: start ");
        intent =new Intent(this,MyService.class);
        intent.putExtra("key123", editText.getText().toString());
        startService(intent);
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stop");
        stopService(intent);

        break;
}
```

MyService.class

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: ");
    String input=intent.getStringExtra("key123");

    Intent notificationIntent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,0);


    Notification notification= new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("TITLE").setContentText(input)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_drive_eta_black_24dp)
            .build();

    startForeground(1,notification);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using Foreground service.

You will get IllegalStateException only when you try to start background service in background.